# Bracket to convert half-height to full- height PCI card?

Tags: hardware, convert, pci, pci-express

I would like to convert a half-height PCI card to full-height card, so some sort of metal bracket is needed.

Does anyone know what such a converter is called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cards backplate will need changing. If one wasn't supplied with the card then you will most likely have to contact the manufacturer to see if they can supply one.